# Setting up a Cruise control with rspec, metrical, rcov for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cruisecontrol.rb

I would like to setup cruisecontrol with rspec and rcov (+ metrical). I see one old post http://jerrett.net/entries/general/enforcing-spec-coverage-with-cruisecontrol-rcov-and-rspec written in 2007. Is it possible for some one to give me more suggestions or related links.